# What is RankBrain?

Tags: google-ranking

According to Google: content, links, and RankBrain are the most important factors in ranking, but what exactly does RankBrain mean?

Comment: It's Google AI (artificial intelligence system) system that is used to provide better relevant results. You won't find much more about it because Google doesn't disclose that type of information.

Comment: Search engines can basically be divided into efforts. If you think of it as only 2 efforts, it would be indexing web pages and search queries. RankBrain brings more AI and better semantic analysis options to the search side of things. There seems to be a better marriage between both efforts instead of being stove piped efforts.

Answer (score 2):

RankBrain is Google's latest *relevancy* algorithm.   It is the part that decides how well pages match queries.

Rank brain replaced Google's historic reliance on keyword search.  It uses artificial intelligence to deduce relationships between words, phrases, and concepts.  It enables queries like this to return relevant results:

[image]

Google doesn't say much about how it actually works.  Search Engine Land has an article that summarizes pretty much everything that Google has said about it: [FAQ: All About The New Google RankBrain Algorithm](http://searchengineland.com/faq-all-about-the-new-google-rankbrain-algorithm-234440)